# To 'link' or 'relate' two items?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, word-usage, computing

I'm developing a system in which users can 'link' separate items by using a 'Link' button. In the database, this 'link' is called a 'relation'. I'm inclined to change the text of the button to 'Relate' instead of 'Link' because it seems more correct. However, I fear users might be confused due to popular usage of the term 'relation'.

For example, you often see a list with 'Related terms' popping up on websites. When you look closely, most of the time this is a list of terms that might have something to do with the current term you have selected, but don't have an actual relation to it. I would rather call it 'Similar terms'.

Might 'link' therefore be a better choice after all? Or is 'relation' much more correct?

Comment: Irrespective of what the database calls it, and notwithstanding that it may or may not be a "relation" in a certain sense, the end user's perspective is that the function of the button is to 'establish a link' and therefore *Link* would be the right label for the button.

Comment: Do you mean like putting together the separate items into one relation (table) in your database?

Comment: @Safira: No, they're still two separate items but you establish a 'relationship' mainly for data integrity. So for example, when you delete item 1, item 2 will also be deleted. Or when you look up item 1, item 2 is shown as well.

Comment: I think, *link* and *relate* are different even in daily English. So a native-English user would understand even if you use *link*. I prefer *link* cause *relate* is used to put items together into a relation (a table), right?

Answer (score 1):

Keep *link*. You need a verb that can be uttered as a command.

Verbs that are commands are best when they don't require and object.

The meaning of [*link*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/link#link__18) as "connect or join up" does not require an object.

The meaning of [*relate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relate#relate__2) as "show a connection between" can take an object. It doesn't always have to, but as a stand alone word *relate* makes me think of its other meaning:

> feel sympathy for or identify with

So I would feel I was commanding the server  to feel sympathy for whatever I've typed in.

If you are set on using *relate* then I would suggest *relate to* be what you use on the button. This removes the ambiguity with the above definition.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was some explanation for the downvote... As for your answer, I doubt if people would feel they're commanding the server to feel sympathy, but I agree 'relate' comes across as more ambiguous.